# Regex filter out space at the end of line

Tags: c#, regex

Why does the following code find nothing in C# but works fine when I tested it online?

```
Match m = Regex.Match(@"abc
cd", "^abc[ \t]*$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

I am using this online regular expressions tester: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

I expect to get "abc"

Comment: Different flavors of Regular Expressions.  Where did you test it online?

Comment: This is just an example. I want to get "abc" without space, suppose I add group to my regex.

Comment: Do you need a `@` before pattern?

Comment: I think I need a @ before pattern

Comment: Are you sure your Regex is working at this website? for me it is not, it is returning spaces if you add them since you are searching for them in your regex... if you want to get the first "abc" after a linestart why not only use "^abc"?

Comment: Did you tick the "Multiline" check box? This is part of parsing. I want to get the exact match. Then use another pattern to match the next thing follows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what's happening here. In my text file the EOL is CRLF. But the C# regex treats the LF as the EOL(which is the '$'). So in my case the regex cannot find the CR and claim a failure. And @"^abc[ \t\r]*$" works.

Answer (score 1):

For a multiline string, you can remove the spaces at the end without using Regex.

```
string trimEnd = string.Join("\n", yourString.Split('\n').Select(x => x.TrimEnd()));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just want to figure out what's wrong with the regex.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get `abc`
you can use: `^abc.*$` instead.

If you want to get all,
you can use: `(?s)^abc.*$` instead.

I think your issue is: [ \t] can not match newline, so you also can change your code to match new line like this:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(@"abc
        cd", @"^abc[ \t\r]*$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Comment: My original expression looks like this @"^[ \t]*\[\[Language =(?'abbr'.+)\[(?'name'.+)\]\]\][ \t]*$". I do want to make sure that apart from what I want what's left is space.

Comment: There is a '*' after the [ \t], So if  no space, it should be fine. And I don't want to match a newline.

Comment: @leon  but in your C# code, the string: @"abc
        cd "  do have newline ,so your regex won't work.

Comment: But is the '$' sign means end of a line?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you haven't captured any group so you get nothing as a result.

First try this:

```
Debug.Print(Regex.IsMatch(@"abc
cd", "^abc[ \t]*$", RegexOptions.Multiline).ToString());
```

You should get `true`, since there is a match.

Then try this: (notice the braces '()' after '^' and before '$')

```
Debug.Print(Regex.Match(@"abc
cd", "^(abc[ \t]*)$", RegexOptions.Multiline).ToString());
```

You should get a result in `Output Window`.

Hope it helps!